# Laravel: how to query a column in a table that contains json data and return only the object that the query matched

Tags: sql, json, laravel

I am working on a project that saves JSON data where each object has 3 components and there are anywhere from 50 to 200 components.

I want to search this JSON column in the database for a key term matching a word or phrase in the components of the objects and return the row with the matching JSON data.

Having built a query input and wiring it up to the controller, view, model, etc I am working on the result displayed in the view,  I would like to return the single object that contains a match to the query.

sample json result

```
["{'result': [{'start': 5.00,", "'end': 10.0,", "'text': 'I would probably have dropped out of'},","{'start': 3.9,", "'end': 3.12,", "'text': 'college without knowing about trio that'},", "{'start': 3.42,", "'end': 5.49,", "'text': \"would have been my scenario if I've\"}]}"]
```

Controller Function

```
`   public function search(Request $request)
{
    $query = $request->input('query');
    $result = JSON::where('description', 'like', "%$query%")->first();
    $process = Collection::make($result->JSON);
    return view('view_JSON', ['result' => $result, 'query' => $query, 'process' => $process]);
}`
```

this is the view, I loop through the collection and the whole JSON data,  I would like here to return the index that matches the sql query result.

VIEW loop

```
@for($i=0; $i< count($process); $i++)
    {{   $process[$i]}}
@endfor
```

So if my query matched college in the JSON column and return the row, How can I display simply:

```
"{'start': 3.9,", "'end': 3.12,", "'text': 'college without knowing about trio that'},"
```

I think saving JSON is a new feature to SQL so Im not familiar with how to work with it as a result yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Laravel Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/collections) class in this case. To achieve this you'll need to cast the json as an array.

## Cast the json as array using Mutators.

As the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) shows, in your model config your field to be casted as array:

**CoolModel.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CoolModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'json_field' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

With this, you can now do `$coolModel->json_field` to get a regular array.

Now, we can even collect this array, to use the [Laravel Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/collections) class:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CoolModel extends Model
{

    // The rest of your code 

    /**
     * Collect the json field.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getJsonField($value)
    {
        return collect($value);
    }
}
```

If all went good, now you can use the power of collections to perform the search of your term:

```php
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $query = $request->input('query');
    $result = CoolModel::where('description', 'like', $query)->first();
    $exact_result = $result->json_field->where('text', $query); // review this.
    $key = $exact_result->keys();

    return view('view_JSON', ['result' => $exact_result, 'key' => $key]);
}
```

Comment: I will try this later today but it looks good to me, pretty sure it is what im looking for just reading your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I haven't test it for lack of time but this should work or at least, serve you as a guide to what to do. The Collection class contain a lot of useful methods that can be used in several use cases. There is [this awesome book](https://adamwathan.me/refactoring-to-collections/) (by adam Wathan) that can help you to get the most of collections.